# LU factorization of a 0-1 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, na.numerical-analysis

I have a rather naive question on LU factorization which probably should be easy to answer. Say I have a matrix with entries only from $\{0,1\}$. When can we expect to get an LU factorization of such a matrix(whenever it exists) with entries $(a)$ from integers? $(b)$ from $\{-1,0,+1\}$?

Comment: In the current form, I don't think the question is on-topic, i.e. about theoretical computer science.

Comment: Actually it is related to a problem for getting capacity of 1-d constrained channels!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a 5-by-5 matrix with a non-integer LU-decomposition.

> > A

A =

```
 1     1     0     1     0
 1     1     1     0     0
 1     0     1     1     0
 1     0     0     1     1
 0     1     0     1     1
```

> > [L U] = lu(A)

L =

```
1.0000         0         0         0         0
1.0000         0    1.0000         0         0
1.0000    1.0000         0         0         0
1.0000    1.0000   -1.0000   -0.5000    1.0000
     0   -1.0000    1.0000    1.0000         0
```

U =

```
1.0000    1.0000         0    1.0000         0
     0   -1.0000    1.0000         0         0
     0         0    1.0000   -1.0000         0
     0         0         0    2.0000    1.0000
     0         0         0         0    1.5000
```

Your questions seems related to unimodular and totally unimodular matrices.

Answer (score 3):

No. Consider the 4-by-4 matrix below.

```
 0     1     1     1
 1     0     1     1
 0     0     0     1
 1     1     0     1
```

Comment: Indeed, as can be verified [here](http://www.bluebit.gr/matrix-calculator/). But is there only one LU decomposition of this matrix (apologies if this is a silly question)?

Comment: comment: Hi this actually produces integral LU matrices.

LU Decomposition:

L:

1.000 0.000 0.000 0.000

0.000 1.000 0.000 0.000

1.000 1.000 1.000 0.000

0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000

U:

1.000 0.000 1.000 1.000

0.000 1.000 1.000 1.000

0.000 0.000 -2.000 -1.000

0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000

Permutation matrix:

0.000 1.000 0.000 0.000

1.000 0.000 0.000 0.000

0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000

0.000 0.000 1.000 0.000